# Java Scanner vs Matcher - Regular Expressions, Matcher works, Scanner doesn't

Tags: java, regex

Why the 1st block works but the 2nd block doesn't?

```
int numberOfDigits = 2;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[01]{"+numberOfDigits+"}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("101100101011010011111000");
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

BLock 2

```
Scanner scannerSegment = new Scanner("101100101011010011111000");
   while(scannerSegment.hasNext(p)){
    String segment = scannerSegment.next(p);
        System.out.println(segment);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Scanner` is not the appropriate utility to retrieve patterns using its `hasNext(Pattern pattern)` method . It will check if the **next complete token** has the requested pattern .

[Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) is the best document.

Some excerpts:

```
hasNext() : Returns true if the next complete token matches the specified 
pattern. A complete token is prefixed and postfixed by input that matches 
the delimiter pattern.`
```

So if you change the input to be delimited by space or any other delimiter ( other delimiters have to be set after defining the `Scanner` object ) , it will work. So this should work(for the current pattern):

```
Scanner scannerSegment = new Scanner("10 11 00 10 10 11 01 00 11 11 10 00");
```

Even this will work(for the current pattern):

```
Scanner scannerSegment = new Scanner("10,11,00,10,10,11,01,00,11,11,10,00");
scannerSegment.useDelimiter(",");
```

EDIT: [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

Comment: Thanks,Do you have any documentation to support?

Comment: Are you sure, that in case of creation `Scanner` object with constructor `Scanner(String source)`, this scanner works with source string as with one complete token? I didn't find nothing to confirm my guess.

Comment: Could you post complete working demo? It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Give me sometime to have my dinner !

Comment: @zvzfhk: Sorry , but I what code are you talking about ? I have made some edits , please check.